# Windows 7 treating my third monitor as an extension to my second rather than detecting it as a stand alone

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I am trying to attach a third monitor to my PC, however I am coming across a rather strange issue. Windows screen resolution is still only showing that I have two monitors connected, but the second has been extended over both the second and third monitors. Basically, it shows as the main display being a normal size, and the secondary as being twice as long as normal. I have my main connected via a the display port, and the second and third are using two of the three mini HDMI ports my video card provides. How do I get windows to accept my third monitor the same as it does my second?

[image: http://i11.photobucket.com/albums/a183/fyrflii/monitor.png]

Comment: What video card do you have?

Comment: Wow, smart! Yes, we need to know the card. Also, do you have the latest drivers? Looks like there may be [others](http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=303880) & [here](http://www.swtor.com/community/archive/index.php/t-358737.html) with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a display driver issue.  You need to open up the display driver's control panel (i.e. nVidia Control Panel, or Catalyst Control Center for AMD/ATI cards) and adjust it there.  For ATI, you want to disable EyeFinity.  For nVidia, I think it's called nView, but I'm not sure (I don't have an nVidia card in my machine, but I've seen it before)